# In R Shiny, how to control the same object from different conditional panels?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my App I would like to allow the user to make changes to the same object from two different conditional panels. (Trust me - from a user perspective, it will facilitate running what will be a complicated model. I know this sounds odd).

This object in common is `table4` derived from `matrix4....` The user should be able to view and change this `table4` from either one of the two conditional panels in the below MWE code, from `condition="input.tabselected==4"` ("Liabilities module") or from `condition="input.tabselected==5"` ("Interest rates").

Changes to `table4` from "Liabilities module" (tab = 4) should also be reactively reflected when the `table4` (or equivalent) is accessed from "Interest rates" module (tab = 5), and vice versa.

Is there a clean and simple way to do this?

With my limited experience, my urge is to replicate 2 versions of  `table4`/`matrix4...` processes in tabs 4 and 5, and then link the two. But this seems duplicative and cumbersome, I bet someone with more experience knows how to more easily do this.

It certainly would be helpful if a solution were accompanied by explanation, as I need to implement this in the full code the MWE derives from.

Below is MWE code:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x,matrix4Input){matrixInput(
  x, value = matrix4Input, rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
  cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),class = "numeric")}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2],
    function(x)gsub("%","",x)),main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")))), uiOutput("Panels")), 
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   actionButton('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                   actionButton('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots')), # close fluid row
                 uiOutput('showTab4Results') 
        ), # close tab panel
        tabPanel("Interest rates", value=5,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   actionButton('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                   actionButton('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots')), # close fluid row
                 uiOutput('showTab5Results') 
        ), # close tab panel
        id = "tabselected"
      ))) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  showTab4Results <- reactiveValues()
  showTab5Results <- reactiveValues()
  
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <- function(){vectorBaseRate(60,input$matrix4[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4",actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates')),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==5",actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates'))
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI

  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
    else {if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {req(input$matrix4)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = baseRate()[,2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})

  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix4', matrix4Default)})

  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtn,
               {showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates values:")))),
                 tableOutput("table4"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$graph4 <-renderPlot(vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtn,{showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(
    fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates plots:")))),
    plotOutput("graph4"))})
  
  output$showTab4Results <- renderUI({showTab4Results$showme})
  output$showTab5Results <- renderUI({showTab5Results$showme})
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix4Input("matrix4",if(is.null(input$matrix4)) matrix4Default else input$matrix4),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 footer = tagList(
                   actionButton("resetRatesStruct","Reset"),
                   modalButton("Close")
                 )))
                 showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example: `Error in ncol(matrix3Default) : object 'matrix3Default' not found`

Comment: OK thanks for the catch. I just removed the line towards the top, colnames(matrix3Default)...,, it was being used for another part of the full code and not needed for this MWE. Sorry about that

Comment: `Error in button2("showRatesValueBtn", "Rates values") : could not find function "button2"`

Comment: I replaced button2 with actionButton, button2 function not used in this MWE. To make sure I have no more deleted custom functions issues, I restarted R and ran this as re-posted without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I got you right but I guess you only need an `or` in the javascript condition of your `conditionalPanel`:

```
condition="input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5"
```

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x,matrix4Input){matrixInput(
  x, value = matrix4Input, rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
  cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),class = "numeric")}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2],
                                                          function(x)gsub("%","",x)),main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Model..."),
                  sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")))), uiOutput("Panels")), 
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                               fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                               fluidRow(
                                 actionButton('showRatesValueBtnA','Rates values'),
                                 actionButton('showRatesPlotBtnA','Rates plots')), # close fluid row
                               uiOutput('showTab4Results') 
                      ), # close tab panel
                      tabPanel("Interest rates", value=5,
                               fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                               fluidRow(
                                 actionButton('showRatesValueBtnB','Rates values'),
                                 actionButton('showRatesPlotBtnB','Rates plots')), # close fluid row
                               uiOutput('showTab5Results') 
                      ), # close tab panel
                      id = "tabselected"
                    ))) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  showTab4Results <- reactiveValues()
  showTab5Results <- reactiveValues()
  
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <- function(){vectorBaseRate(60,input$matrix4[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5",actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates'))
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
    else {if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {req(input$matrix4)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = baseRate()[,2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table5 <- output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtnA,
               {showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates values:")))),
                 tableOutput("table4"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtnB,
               {showTab5Results$showme <- tagList(
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates values:")))),
                 tableOutput("table5"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$graph5 <- output$graph4 <- renderPlot(vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtnA,{showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(
    fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates plots:")))),
    plotOutput("graph4"))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtnB,{showTab5Results$showme <- tagList(
    fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("You are viewing Rates plots:")))),
    plotOutput("graph5"))})
  
  output$showTab4Results <- renderUI({showTab4Results$showme})
  output$showTab5Results <- renderUI({showTab5Results$showme})
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix4Input("matrix4",if(is.null(input$matrix4)) matrix4Default else input$matrix4),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 footer = tagList(
                   actionButton("resetRatesStruct","Reset"),
                   modalButton("Close")
                 )))
                 showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Here is a simplified version avoiding the `reactiveValues`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x, matrix4Input) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix4Input,
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(
      extend = FALSE,
      names = FALSE,
      editableNames = FALSE
    ),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x, y) {
  a <- rep(y, x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)
}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w, x, y, z) {
    plot(
      w[, 1],
      sapply(w[, 2], function(x)
        gsub("%", "", x)),
      main = x,
      xlab = y,
      ylab = z
    )
  }

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(
    strong("Base Input Panel")
  ))), uiOutput("Panels")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Liabilities module",
      value = 4,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates4",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab4Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    tabPanel(
      "Liabilities module",
      value = 5,
      fluidRow(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "showRates5",
          label = h5(strong(helpText(
            "Select model output to view:"
          ))),
          choices = c('Rates values', 'Rates plots'),
          selected = 'Rates values',
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        uiOutput('showTab5Results')
      )
    ),
    # close tab panel
    id = "tabselected"
  ))
) # close tabset panel, main panel, page with sidebar

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  matrix4   <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate  <-
    function() {
      vectorBaseRate(60, input$matrix4[1, 1])
    } # Must remain in server section
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'))
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)) {
      DF <- NULL
    }
    else {
      if (input$modRates < 1) {
        DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = 0.2)
      }
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        DF <- cbind(Period = 1:60, BaseRate = baseRate()[, 2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    DF
  }) # close reactive
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {
    updateMatrixInput(session, 'matrix4', matrix4Default)
  })
  
  output$table5 <- output$table4 <- renderTable({
    vectorRates()
  })
  
  output$graph5 <- output$graph4 <- renderPlot({
    vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(), "A Variable", "Period", "Rate")
  })
  
  output$showTab4Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates4 == 'Rates values') {
      tagList(fluidRow(h5(strong(
        helpText("You are viewing Rates values:")
      ))),
      tableOutput("table4"))
    } else {
      tagList(fluidRow(h5(strong(
        helpText("You are viewing Rates plots:")
      ))),
      plotOutput("graph4"))
    }
  })
  
  output$showTab5Results <- renderUI({
    if (input$showRates5 == 'Rates values') {
      tagList(fluidRow(h5(strong(
        helpText("You are viewing Rates values:")
      ))),
      tableOutput("table5"))
    } else {
      tagList(fluidRow(h5(strong(
        helpText("You are viewing Rates plots:")
      ))),
      plotOutput("graph5"))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   matrix4Input("matrix4", if (is.null(input$matrix4))
                     matrix4Default
                     else
                       input$matrix4),
                   useShinyjs(),
                   footer = tagList(
                     actionButton("resetRatesStruct", "Reset"),
                     modalButton("Close")
                   )
                 ))
               } # close modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
              ) # close observeEvent
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you ismirsehregal. That change allows user to access the modify modal from "Interest rates" tab too, and the input changes show when viewed in the "Liabilities module" tab main panel. However, how do I reflect the same rates table and rates plot that appear in the "Liabilities module" tab main panel, in the "Interest rates" tab main panel too?

Comment: Basically, both tabs offer an avenue to the same thing.

Comment: Pleas check my edit - I think we've had that before: all shiny input elements need a uniqie ID. You have had 2 pairs of buttons sharing the same ID. This does not work.

Comment: And btw. is there any specific reason for putting UI elements in `reactiveValues`? To me it seems overly complicated regarding the functionality of your app. `renderUI` itself is reactive.

Comment: Ahh I was hoping it would be possible to have multiple buttons share the same ID. The first set of code you posted, with all my clumsy reactive values, works great. The simplified version, avoiding the reactiveValues, gives me error "Warning: Error in <-: object 'showTab4Results' not found" when I click on the "Modify..." action button. I'll look at it closer in the morning and see if I can solve it.

Comment: As for putting UI elements in reactiveValues, I think I did this originally to stop elements flashing by when invoking the App. Maybe not needed anymore. It's gotten clumsy as I've fiddled with it and grown it.

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal, I got the 2nd simplified version of yours to work by reinserting "showTab4Results <- reactiveValues()" into server section. In general, I also ended up with so many reactives because often when the code as it's being developed doesn't work, a simple solution is to make an object reactive.

Comment: And I prefer those radio buttons you used in your simplified version, thanks for that. Cleaner look. I'll adopt.

Comment: Please see my edit. You don't need the `reactiveValue`. I just forgot to delete the line `showTab4Results$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))`.

Comment: Yes, I see. That works nicely. With tabs 4 and 5 joined by an OR (output$Panels <- renderUI({ conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'))), will it be possible for the side and main panels for tabs 4 and 5 to diverge? They'll share the same "Modify Rates" action button in sidebar panel, and same "Rates values" and "Rates plots" buttons in main panel; but from there they'll have additional and differing action buttons in both panels. I'm trying to remove the OR to accomplish this, or can I keep OR?

Comment: The `or` is only related to the conditional display of the `modRates` button. All other content may behave differently

Comment: I couldn´t get the 2 tabs to diverge in terms of adding different action buttons (leaving the "Modify Rates" action button in the sidebar panel as it currently works). To make this cleaner I just posted another question addressing this need.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to nest conditional panels. To solve this, I used the following:

```
output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5", actionButton('modRates', 'Modify Rates'),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.tabselected==4", actionButton('test', 'Test'),
        ) # close 2nd conditional panel
    ) # close 1st conditional panel
  }) # close renderUI
```

In place of the following used in the original MWE code posting:

```
output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4 || input.tabselected==5",actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates'))
  }) # close renderUI
```